# congruence proof: Prove that there is no integer such that $x≡2 \pmod 6$ and $x≡3 \pmod 9$ are both true.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove that there is no Integer such that $x≡2 \pmod 6$ and $x≡3 \pmod 9$ are both true.

How should I approach this question?
I attempted using contra-positive proof, so $x=6p+2$ and $x=9q+3$ where $p,q$ are integers.
Then $6p+2=9q+3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=6k+2=9l+3$ for some $k,l\in N$ ,

$3$ divides $9l+3\Rightarrow 3|6k+2$

What does $3|(6k+2)$ imply?

Doesn't this imply the impossible fact $3|2$.

So it is a contraction to the given fact.

Comment: thanks! that really helps.

Comment: you are welcome.....it was my pleasure helping you.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be true that for integers $k,k'$ we have $6k-9k'=1$ or $3k''=1$ for some integer $k''$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea and you are doing well.  You said you got to $$6p+2=9q+3.$$

You are almost done!  Move the $6p$ to the other side:

$$\begin{align}2 & =  9q + 3 - 6p\\
2 & = 3(q+1-2p)\end{align}$$

There is a multiple of 3 on the right, so it says that 2 is equal to a multiple of 3.  Do you have the contradiction you want?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$x\equiv2\pmod 6\equiv2\pmod 3$$

and $$x\equiv3\pmod 9\equiv0\pmod 3$$